# Binary trees post traversal into a linked list

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, recursion, linked-list, binary-tree

I'm studying for my exam and I can't figure out how to answer this question.

Make a function that returns a linked list of the post traversal of a binary tree. You cannot use any containers to store your data before hand and it must be recursive.

So I can't take the post traversal, put it in a list and then iterate through it to make a linked list.

There was another question that said to do the same thing but for a inorder traversal and this was the solution.

There are two solutions. One that I don't understand and a clear version of that one

THIS IS THE MAIN SOLUTION

```
def inorder(root: BTNode) -> LLNode:
"""Return the first node in a linked list that contains every value from the
binary tree rooted at root, listed according to an inorder traversal.

>>> b = BTNode(1, BTNode(2), BTNode(3))
>>> repr(inorder(b))
'LLNode(2, LLNode(1, LLNode(3)))'
>>> b2 = BTNode(4, BTNode(5))
>>> b3 = BTNode(7, b, b2)
>>> str(inorder(b3))
'2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 5 -> 4'
>>> # from the handout...
>>> left = BTNode('B', None, BTNode('D', BTNode('G')))
>>> right = BTNode('C', BTNode('E'), BTNode('F'))
>>> root = BTNode('A', left, right)
>>> str(inorder(root))
'B -> G -> D -> A -> E -> C -> F'
"""
return _inorder(root)[0]


def _inorder(root: BTNode) -> (LLNode, LLNode):
"""Return the first and last nodes in a linked list that contains every
value from the binary tree rooted at root, listed according to an inorder
traversal.
"""
if root:
    head_left, tail_left = _inorder(root.left)
    head_right, tail_right = _inorder(root.right)
    node_root = LLNode(root.item, head_right)
    if tail_left:
        tail_left.link = node_root
    return head_left or node_root, tail_right or node_root
else:
    return None, None
```

CLEAR SOLUTION

```
def inorder(root: BTNode) -> LLNode:
"""Return the first node in a linked list that contains every value from the
binary tree rooted at root, listed according to an inorder traversal.

>>> b = BTNode(1, BTNode(2), BTNode(3))
>>> repr(inorder(b))
'LLNode(2, LLNode(1, LLNode(3)))'
>>> b2 = BTNode(4, BTNode(5))
>>> b3 = BTNode(7, b, b2)
>>> str(inorder(b3))
'2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 5 -> 4'
>>> # from the handout...
>>> left = BTNode('B', None, BTNode('D', BTNode('G')))
>>> right = BTNode('C', BTNode('E'), BTNode('F'))
>>> root = BTNode('A', left, right)
>>> str(inorder(root))
'B -> G -> D -> A -> E -> C -> F'
"""
return _inorder(root)[0] # what must this first item represent?


def _inorder(root: BTNode) -> (LLNode, LLNode): # what are these 1st and 2nd things?
"""Return the first and last nodes in a linked list that contains every
value from the binary tree rooted at root, listed according to an inorder
traversal.

>>> left = BTNode('B', None, BTNode('D', BTNode('G')))
>>> right = BTNode('C', BTNode('E'), BTNode('F'))
>>> root = BTNode('A', left, right)
>>> str(inorder(root))
'B -> G -> D -> A -> E -> C -> F'
"""    

if not root:
    return None, None

    else:
    # Start off by making a new node of our item, with None for a link
    # Obviously we will need to replace that None if we have a right branch
    new_node = LLNode(root.item)

    # Recursive call on right branch gives us its head and tail        
    right_head, right_tail = _inorder(root.right)

    # The link on our new node should be the right head, even if it's None
    new_node.link = right_head

    # Ultimately the tail for this whole node will be the rightmost tail
    # If there is no right side, though, this node is the rightmost tail
    if not right_tail:
        right_tail = new_node

    # Recursive call on left branch gives us its head and tail
    left_head, left_tail = _inorder(root.left)

    # If there is a left tail, we should string our current node to the end
    if left_tail:
        left_tail.link = new_node

    # Ultimately the head for this whole node will be the leftmost head
    # If there is no left head, though, this node is the leftmost head
    if not left_head:
        left_head = new_node

     # Return the leftmost head and the rightmost tail
    return left_head, right_tail
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what keeps you from understanding the main solution. The comment explains it very well. In any case, the recursive call to `_inorder(root.left)` flattens the left subtree, and returns the head and tail of the resulting list. Same way, the recursive call to `_inorder(root.right)` flattens the right subtree. Now you have two lists,

```
head_left-> ... ->tail_left
head_right-> ... ->tail_right
```

stitch them with the root,

```
head_left-> ... ->tail_left->root->head_right-> ... ->tail_right
```

and return the resulting list

```
head_left-> ... ->tail_right
```

To achieve the postorder, stitch them as in

```
head_left-> ... ->tail_left->head_right-> ... ->tail_right->root
```

and return

```
head_left-> ... ->root
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me understand it a bit more. The part I don't understand in the main solution if tail_left: tail_left.link = node_root. I don't get it because tail_left is not being returned so why does linking it to a node matter or is it being linked somewhere in the recursive call to the head_left? Also I don't understand the syntax for head_left or node_root, tail_right or node_root.

Comment: @andresmejia Linking tail_left makes the lists connected.

Comment: After putting some time into it, I couldn't figure it out. Do you mind telling me the solution? My exam has past already, this is now just out of curiousity

Comment: @andresmejia I am afraid I cannot add more than you already have in _Main solution_ from your original post.